# Upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04, gnome-settings-daemon equivalent?

Tags: 16.04, unity, i3-wm, gnome-settings-daemon

**Some background:** I recently upgraded to 16.04 from 14.04 on a 2nd gen [Thinkpad X1 Carbon with the adaptive keyboard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wtOkeHt3OS4). It seems Unity picks up volume / brightness keys correctly on this model. But if I manually start up an `i3` session, these keys aren't picked up. I used to be able to manually start `gnome-settings-daemon` which would fix this.

**Question:** What is the equivalent of `gnome-settings-daemon` on 16.04? Or, equally as useful: how to find out which daemon / program in my Unity is able to pick up these keys so I can start the program manually in my i3 sessions?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Take a look at running i3 with a gnome session. You can use i3 as the window manager, and have gnome handle all of the multimedia key functionality.

- [i3 with Gnome-Flashback](http://zork.net/~st/jottings/gnome-i3.html)
- [Using i3 with Gnome](http://blog.hugochinchilla.net/2013/03/using-gnome-3-with-i3-window-manager/)